# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException Spring Batch xml configuration

Tags: xml, java-8, spring-batch, quartz

I have a batch process which executes weekly on Fridays. Spring xml configuration is as follows.

```
   <bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggerpo">
          
        <ref bean="cronTriggerForProcessOrder"/>
        
      
      </property>
  </bean>

    
    <bean id="cronTriggerForProcessOrder" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerFactoryBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobForProcessOrders" />
        <property name="cronExpression" value="0 0 0 ? * FRI" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jobForProcessOrders"
        class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="ProcessOrdersController" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="processOrders"/>
        <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
    </bean>
 <bean id="ProcessOrdersController" class="com.java.app.web.controller.ProcessOrderController">
        
    </bean>
```

In the controller removed @controller annotation as it says the controller initialized multiple times. Now I am getting an error while tomcat startup .

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.java.app.web.controller.ProcessOrderController.processOrders()
```

The method *processOrders* do exists in the controller.

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/processorder")
public class ProcessOrderController {

@RequestMapping(value="/processOrders.do")
    public ModelAndView processOrders(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws AppException{
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        mav.setViewName("processorder");
        processOrders();
        return mav;
    }
    }
```

I am not sure what mistake I made in this. Could any one please help me to understand ? I can provide more info on request.

Also would like to know how I can eliminate xml configuration and use pure annotation based code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's trying to find a method without parameters, but yours `HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res`.

As a test, I suggest you to try to remove those parameters. If you don't get that error, you know at least in which direction to look ;)

Comment: Great the error is gone. But this was working earlier the same way.  Let me see whether the job is working fine. Any way accepting this as answer.

Comment: It will be good if you can help me to understand this , because the above code was working earlier I just made some changes in the code. Created a mutlimodule project hence  face this issue.

Comment: Hi, I don't know how the code was before and I haven't seen much of the current code, so I can only guess.
As I see you are calling a processOrders(no parameters) from the processOrders(withParameters), I believe you expect the schedule job to call the first one(calling the second wouldn't make sense). But as I see that he method is visible from the the processOrders(with params), my guess is that is protected, private or package-private.

But as said, without seeing the code, I cannot say much more.